# Can we generate single AAR file by merging two android library modules?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-architecture

I am having multimodule android project

test-app : apply pugin com.android.application ( testing application utilising both modeule 1 and module 2)

module 1 : apply plugin: com.android.library
module 2 : apply plugin : com.android.library

Module 2 is depends on module 1

How to generate single AAR which will have code from both module ?

When I try to rebuild project it is creating module specific AAR file

In my case 2 different AAR file was getting generated.